# variable cannot be reached inside foreach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api-nodejs-client, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am trying to build a webhook for dialogue flow but cannot access some variable in code
when i run code
match comes out to be undefined

```
var findclass = (data, day, time) => {
      var match;
      data.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.day === day && entry.time === time) {
          console.log("found");
          match=entry;//this statement has no effect on above var match
//instead it creates a new local variable
        }
      });
      return match;
    }



exports.tt = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  let qr = request.body.queryResult;
  let day = qr.parameters.day;
  let time = parseInt(qr.parameters.time.substring(11, 13));
  let data = [
    {
      day: "monday",
      time: 11,
      type: "lecture",
      batches: ["A", "B1", "B4", "B3", "B2"],
      subject: {
        name: "Basic Numerical Methods",
        name_short: "BNM",
        coursecode: "17B1NMA531",
        coursecode_short: "17MA531"
      },
      class: "CS1",
      teachers: "SSH",
      semester: 5
    },
    {
      day: "monday",
      time: 15,
      type: "lecture",
      batches: ["A6", "A9"],
      subject: {
        name: "Environmental Science",
        name_short: "EVS",
        coursecode: "15B11GE301",
        coursecode_short: "GE301"
      },
      class: "CS1",
      teachers: "EKT",
      semester: 5
    }]
var match = findclass(data, day, time);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(match));
  if (match) {
    response.send({
      fulfillmentText: `Yes, ${match.subject.name_short || match.subject.name}`
    });
  } else {
    response.send({
      fulfillmentText: `No class on ${day} ,${time} hr`
    });
  }
```

also vscode code is showing var match is unused if i remove return match statement,this means it is not considering match = entry , but i cannot understand why ?

Comment: The VS Code "unused variable" means, that the value is never read.

Comment: I mean the variable never gets assigned any value. So function returns undefined always . even if console.log prints "found" .

Comment: Does the code work if you switch it to a `for` loop instead? Since `forEach` loops create a function, the scopes might be different. Also, `forEach` loops are slower.

Comment: No, I tried for loop and also every instead of foreach.The problem always remains same , Inside the loop it creates a new variable of match but does not use which is already declared.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason but two changes fixed the code

1) Adding "use strict" at the top.
2) defining function as

```
const findclass = () => {}
```

instead of var

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your declaration of:

```
var match ...
```

is being hoisted ... see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

In your code you have declared:

```
var match ...
```

twice.  I think the declaration in the body of the findClass function might want to be changed to a local variable ...

```
let match;
```

(This is a guess, will delete this answer on request or if better answer comes along).

Comment: Already tried this with no luck . I think cloud functions webhook forces some kind of "use strict" ( just a probability)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that nothing is actually matching in the loop, and therefore `match` remains undefined. Have you made sure something is actually matching in the loop?

Also, in VSCode, if you are just assigning a variable, but not using it (e.g., in a `return` statement), it will show the variable as being unused, so that is expected.

Comment: I am sure it matches because "found" is printed on the console.